# Facebook reverts back to Top Stories even after changing to Most Recent

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I am aware of the question [Facebook home page post display changed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18639/facebook-home-page-post-display-changed) and its answers, however, I think this issue is slightly different.  Facebook either brought back this feature or its more integrated into the UI now.

I prefer to have "Most Recent" selected, so I can linearly go through the timeline and see what my friends have posted.  On the mobile version of FB, I can set it as Recent, and it never reverts back to "Top Stories".  However, on the main website when I'm accessing it from my laptop, the setting seems to revert back constantly.  I realize that this is part of their marketing to keep me on the site looking at "Top Stories", but I'm wondering why it sticks on the mobile version, then.

Is there a setting to permanently select "Most Recent" for posts that's buried in the settings somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just bookmark [this facebook link](http://facebook.com/?sk=h_chr)

```
http://facebook.com/?sk=h_chr
```

Other than this I don't think there is a better way. There were browser plugins that did this but they don't work now.

Comment: That's actually how it is in the address bar currently, and it has not reset so far, but over time it seems to.  Not sure if they do it on their autorefreshes or something.  Good suggestion, though.

Comment: I've been using this for a few months now, works fine. Not sure when it started, but it's been like that for quite some time now.
EDIT: You will manually need to refresh for new posts though.